# Assertj Comparing extracted which are String arrays

Tags: java, json, assertj

In my case I need to request the set of names from two different systems and verify they are equal (regardless order). Most probably I don't understand smth, but this code works fine:

```
assertThat(asList(assertThat(firstJSON)
    .flatExtracting("innerObject")
    .extracting("name")).stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .containsExactlyElementsOf(
            asList(assertThat(secondJSON)
                    .flatExtracting("innerObject")
                    .extracting("name")).stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

, but it looks really ugly and I want something like this:

```
assertThat(firstJSON)
    .flatExtracting("innerObject")
    .extracting("name")
    .containsExactlyElementsOf(
            assertThat(secondJSON)
                    .flatExtracting("innerObject")
                    .extracting("name"));
```

I've tried many functions like `isSubsetOf()` or `containsOnly()`, also I tried putting casting here and there but always catching some exception/error.

How do I compare them?

Comment: It should really be `assertThat(getNamesOutOf(firstJSON)).isEqualTo(getNamesOutOf(secondJSON))`. We could help implementing `getNamesOutOf()` is we knew the type and structure of firstJSON and secondJSON.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I would consider using https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit instead of AssertJ, it provides nice navigation features to assert subsection of your JSON data.